# How to use cloudFirestore with RoomDatabase? Or build which download data only once, not every time from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I am building an app which has a lot of data 700 entries which must be download everytime if user want to. Ofc it's no need to download every time from firestore this 700 entries, but I could save them on phone, and use data from roomdatabase and only when will be update,delete or new entries update the roomdatabase from firestore cloud. I was looking for solution like that but can't find it.